# How to enable digital vibrance in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia

I have a GTX 950m I would really like to enable digital vibrance on ubuntu, just like I was able to on windows 10. However, in the nvidia GUI, there is no tab which has the vibrance settings. Is it even possible in Ubuntu?

Thanks.